# How to update the client side javascript based on something on the server?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've researched this, but it's hard to find something when you don't know the best way to do it or even how to begin. I don't have any code obviously, so i'll describe my issue and hopefully someone can point me to the correct way to solve this :

ok let's say I have a page with a javascript function called "myfunction1" that fires off every x seconds by using setinterval in js. What I want it to do is, (using AJAX perhaps?) when "myfunction1" is called, call a php script that will check something in the database. If a certain condition is TRUE, I want a specific function to be called in javascript on the client side. If FALSE, I want it to call a different function.

My intuition makes me think the way to do it is to have the ajax call the php checking script, then echo the proper javascript code based on if true or false. But how would I go about doing that? I know how to use ajax to change the .innerhtml of a tag, but can you use it in this way to rewrite inside a script tag?? My head's spinning, hope I made some sense and one of you can point me the right way

Comment: A good place to start would be looking into Web Sockets. But making a plain AJAX request and reacting to the response would work just as well.

Comment: You're right about using AJAX. You certainly don't want to run code that the server returns, though. Just have the server return a 1 or 0, and then use that in an `if` statement to decide which function to run (after writing both, of course).

Comment: You'd probably want to use a javascript framework which supports data binding like angular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binding
Makes DOM manipulation much simpler.

Comment: Simple: jQuery + `$.ajax`. Better: Angular or React with data binding as sboesch suggests. Even better: Either of those + Websockets to keep a connection open, though that can be annoying with PHP as a back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX would probably be the simplest solution and can be used to evaluate returning `script` or you can manually validate/display the response from the `XmlHttpRequest` that the server processed.

For example when using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types) You can change the `dataType` option to `script`.
Otherwise you can manually program the validation in the `success` callback, like below, using JSON.

**javascript (jQuery)**

```
jQuery(function($) {
   'use strict';
   var element = $('#myElement');
   var ajax = null;
   var ajaxTimeout = 0;

   function myFunction1() {
       if (null !== ajax) {
          //prevent overlapping ajax requests
          ajax.abort();
          ajax = null;
       }
       ajax = $.ajax({
         url: '/response.php',
         method: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
            //parse the server side response
            if (data.result === true) {
               trueFunction(data);
            } else {
               falseFunction(data);
            }
            ajax = null;
         }
      });
   }

   //custom functions for true or false and setInterval.
   function trueFunction(data) {
      element.html('Success: ' + data.value);
   }

   function falseFunction(data) {
      element.html('Failed: ' + data.value);
   }

   ajaxTimeout = window.setInterval(myFunction1, 1000);
});
```

**response.php**

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$date = new \DateTime;
echo json_encode((object) [
    'value' => 'Hello World ' . $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a'), 
    'result' => true
]);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks to all. I ended up doing it in an imperfect way that was simple enough and works. I set up the client to check the database and return a simple 3 field xml snippet, which I then parsed manually in js and acted accordingly. didn't bother with the json. works like a charm